# Defining Euclidean global $\rm AdS$

Tags: differential-geometry, topology, ads-cft, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

- How does one see that the Euclidean $\rm AdS$ is the same as the hyperbolic space at the same dimension ie $EAdS_n = \mathbb{H}_n = SO_0(n,1)/SO(n)$?

  Or is this to be seen as the definition of Euclidean AdS?
- Now one can see two kinds of global coordinates metric on this $EAdS_n$,

  - as given in equation 4.4 (page 13) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.3627).
  - as given in equation 3.11 (page 18) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0440).

  Is there any natural relationship between the two?
  And are they describing the same space - Euclidean AdS?
- In what sense is the description in the second link a foliation of $AdS_{n+1}$ by $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{H}_{n-1}$? And is the existence of such a foliation by hyperbolic cylinders anyhow related to the fact that Euclidean AdS is itself the same as the hyperbolic plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The general idea is to see maximally symmetric manifolds of dimension $n$ embedded in a manifold of dimension $n+1$, with a constraint :

$$\epsilon_{-1} x_{-1}^2+\epsilon_0 x_{0}^2 +\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_i^2= \epsilon_{-1} R^2 \tag{1}$$
where $\epsilon_{-1} =\pm1, \epsilon_0 =\pm1$
with the metrics :

$$\epsilon_{-1} dx_{-1}^2+\epsilon_0 dx_{0}^2 +\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}dx_i^2\tag{2}$$
for the embedding manifold.

[EDIT]

The maximally symmetric manifold could be written $M_n = G/L$, where $G$  is the "global" symmetry (inherited from the embedding manifold), and $L$ is a "local" symmetry. The "global" symmetry is $SO(p,q)$, where $p$ is the number of space coordinates and $q$ the number of time coordinates. The local symmetry could be obtained from the global symmetry by fixing the coordinate $x_{-1}$, which is a time-coordinate if $\epsilon_{-1}=-1$, and a space-coordinate if $\epsilon_{-1}=1$. So, the "local symmetry" is $SO(p,q-1)$ if $\epsilon_{-1}=-1$, and $SO(p-1,q)$ if $\epsilon_{-1}=1$

[/EDIT]

So, such a maximally symmetric manifold $M_n$could be written, with a general formula :

$$M_n = SO(n + \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_{-1} + \epsilon_0),1-\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_{-1} + \epsilon_0))\\/SO(n+\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_0-1),\frac{1}{2}(1-\epsilon_0))\tag{3}$$

The $AdS_n$ manifold corresponds to the case $\epsilon_{-1}=\epsilon_0=-1$, so 
$$AdS_n = SO(n-1,2)/SO(n-1,1)\tag{4}$$

The euclidean version of the  $AdS_n$ manifold, corresponds to  a change of sign of $\epsilon_0$, that is $\epsilon_{-1}=-1,\epsilon_0=+1$, this is the manifold :

$$H_n = SO(n,1)/SO(n)\tag{5}$$

[EDIT]

The euclideanization can be simply viewed as transferring one time degree of freedom to one space degree of freedom for both the "global" symmetry and the "local symmetry"

[/EDIT]

2) The two papers are different. The second paper gives the metrics for an AdS space, while the first paper is doing a construction for appearing $SO(N,1)$ as an analytic continuation of $SO(N+1)$, and more precisely, starting from the metrics of a sphere, and making some analytic continuation on the coordinates to get the metrics of the hyperbolic space.

3) In the second paper, the expression of the $AdS_{n+1}$ metrics could be considered at $\tilde \tau$ constant. At fixed $\tilde \tau$, the spatial slice is a product of a real dimension $R$ ($\rho$) by the  hyperbolic $H_{n-1}$ metrics:

$ds^2(\tilde \tau$ constant) $= \frac{d\rho^2}{(\rho^2/L^2-1)}+\rho^2 \underbrace{(du^2+sinh^2(u)d\Omega^2_{(d-2)})}_{H_{n-1} metrics}$$\tag{6}$

> 4) "And is the existence of such a foliation by hyperbolic cylinders
>   anyhow related to the fact that Euclidean AdS is itself the same as
>   the hyperbolic plane?"

I have no real good answer about this last point, but note that the dimensions are not the same, the euclidean version  is $H_{d+1}$, while the foliation is $R*H_{d-1}$

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I am not being very clear about the comparison between the two metrics in my two links. Can you elaborate if they are talking of the same space? The metric in my second link seems to be that on $\mathbb{H}_n$ but the metric in my first link seems to have an uniform sign and hence seems to be a sphere! But the first link authors seem to claim that it is $\mathbb{H}_n$ too! How?

Comment: @user6818 : In the first link, the part of the metrics which does not include time (and skipping the minus sign) is the metrics of $H_{2n}$ in spherical polar coordinates. See for instance the discussion about some different version of the $H_3$  metrics in this [paper](http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/Kurs.pdf), pages $14$ to $18$. See particularly the formula $(58)$ page $18$ : this is the metrics of $H_3$ in spherical polar coordinates, compare to the formula in your first link, and you will see it is the same thing.

Comment: So in the first link reference one is saying that $ds^2_{\mathbb{H}_{2n+1}} (= ds^2_{EAdS_{2n+1}})= cosh^2\rho dt^2 + d\rho^2 + sinh^2\rho d\Omega^2_{2n-1}$ and in the second link reference one is saying that $ds^2_{\mathbb{H}_{n-1}} = du^2 + sinh^2(u)d\Omega^2_{n-2}$  - is this interpretation right?

Comment: Let me ask the question in another way - is equation 3.11 on page 18 of my second link describing $EAdS_{d+1} = \mathbb{H}_{d+1}$? (may be after making $\tilde{\tau}$ imaginary?) If yes how does it match with the other two metrics given above?

Comment: @user6818 : As I already said in my previous comment, in the first link, if you fix time (and skip minus sign), you will get the metrics of $H_{2n}$ in spherical polar coordinates. In the second link, the $3.11$ equation correspond to the full  $AdS_{d+1}$ metrics, the term $du^2 + sinh^2(u)d\Omega^2_{d-2}$ represents the $H_{d-1}$ metrics, in spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: Isn't the claim stronger? That even if you do include the $cosh^2 \rho dt^2$ part in the first link metric the result is a metric on $\mathbb{H}_{2n+1}$? So you are saying that the metric in the second link is that on $AdS_{d+1}$ and NOT on $EAdS_{d+1}$? And if I make $\tilde{\tau}$ imaginary then do I get the $EAdS_{d+1}$ metric?

Comment: @user6818 : For the second link, if you follow the paper, it is clearly the metrics for $AdS_{d+1}$. For the first link, the paper claims (in skipping the minus sign) that the total metrics  is $AdS_{2n+1}$ metrics. I am not sure of this, but I am going to search if is really one of the possible metrics for $AdS_{2n+1}$.

Comment: @user6818 : So, now I have found an other [reference](http://www.physics.ntua.gr/cosmo09/Milos2009/Milos%20Talks%202009/1st%20day/Charmousis%20Paper.pdf) formula $1.20$. By taking $l=1,u=\rho$  in this formula, we get : $ds^2(AdS_{2n+1}) = - cosh^2\rho dt^2 + d\rho^2 + sinh^2\rho d\Omega^2_{2n-1}$

Comment: @user6818 : So I think you are right, and that $ds^2_{\mathbb{H}_{2n+1}} (= ds^2_{EAdS_{2n+1}})= cosh^2\rho dt^2 + d\rho^2 + sinh^2\rho d\Omega^2_{2n-1}$